# Is SSRC=0 in RTP packet header valid?

Tags: network-programming, sip, rtp, tcpdump

With reference to [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550)

> Synchronization source (SSRC): The source of a stream of RTP
> packets, identified by a 32-bit numeric SSRC identifier carried in
> the RTP header so as not to be dependent upon the network address.

RFC states that SSRC is a 32 bit number.
So, would it be acceptable to have SSRC zero **(SSRC=0x00)** in RTP header?

Answer (score 2):

All binary values on 32 bits are allowed for **SSRC** from 0 to 2^32 -1. 
But as stated in RFC :

1. **SSRC** SHOULD be a random value;
2. **SSRC** collision MUST be detected.

   **SSRC**: 32 bits
         The SSRC field identifies the synchronization source.  This
         identifier SHOULD be chosen randomly, with the intent that no two
         synchronization sources within the same RTP session will have the
         same SSRC identifier.

   8. **SSRC** Identifier Allocation and Use

      The SSRC identifier carried in the RTP header and in various fields
      of RTCP packets is a random 32-bit number that is required to be
      globally unique within an RTP session.  It is crucial that the number
      be chosen with care in order that participants on the same network or
      starting at the same time are not likely to choose the same number.

      It is not sufficient to use the local network address (such as an
      IPv4 address) for the identifier because the address may not be
      unique.  Since RTP translators and mixers enable interoperation among
      multiple networks with different address spaces, the allocation
      patterns for addresses within two spaces might result in a much
      higher rate of collision than would occur with random allocation.

      Multiple sources running on one host would also conflict.

      It is also not sufficient to obtain an SSRC identifier simply by
      calling random() without carefully initializing the state.

Comment: I understand the RFC and that the SSRC could be any random 32bit number. But it is strange that MS Lync drops RTP packet with SSRC=0x00. This makes me wonder if ZERO is a valid random 32-bit number or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, zero is a valid SSRC value and should be accounted for.

If the other party consistently uses 0 as a SSRC value, its entropy could be questioned ([xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/) and [dilbert](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)). As with many VoIP related RFCs, the implementations vary substantially to the point where most endpoint software (UAS, UAC and especially B2BUAs) have to accommodate for protocol deviations. Think of the different DTMF implementations and the less compliant applications out there.